# removing debug code with google closure REST service?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

How do I remove debug code from javascript with the google closure REST service.
I know that I have to specify the debug variable to the JS compiler like this:
--define='DEBUG=false'
(with DEBUG being used in if conditions).
But how do I specify this to the REST service:  http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home
I tried this, but it doesn't work. That is: the code is optimized but it still contains the debug code :(

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS

-- define='DEBUG=false'

// ==/ClosureCompiler==


/** @define {boolean} */
var DEBUG = true;

/**@constructor*/
function MyObject() {
this.test = 4;
if (DEBUG) {
this.toString = function () { return "test object"; };
}
}
window['MyObject'] = MyObject
```

Answer (score 0):

The Closure REST service usually maps command line options to the lines between the comment block.  Options are prefixed with "@" with the "=" sign stripped off.  It, however, does not seem to work for @define (which should map to --define).  I suspect that the REST code is confused with the extra "=" in DEBUG=false.

This should work:

```
@define DEBUG=false
```

or

```
@define 'DEBUG=false'
```

but doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

The `define` parameter is currently not supported for the REST service.

[Only these](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref) and [these](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/AdditionalWebserviceOptions) parameters are supported.